# Configure one 02 Cassandra DB to be a replica of the other

Tags: cassandra

I have 02 cassandra db, is it possible to configure that one db will be a replica of the another one? I've joined them and this the what it says:

```
Note: Ownership information does not include topology, please specify a keyspace. 
Address         DC          Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token                                       
                                                                                           1                                           
127.0.0.1       datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  51.9 KB         100.00%             0                                           
127.0.0.2       datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  51.9 KB         0.00%               1
```

When I create some data in 127.0.0.1, there is no updated data in 127.0.0.2, did I misunderstand something here :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sync 02 nodes in Cassandra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114190/sync-02-nodes-in-cassandra)

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are asking, what are you looking to acheive with this setup?

I suggest you to investigate this setup, I think this might serve your purpose. Setup a cassandra cluster with two datacenters, with replication factors as {DC1: 1 and DC2: 1} and replication strategy being 'NetworkTopologyStrategy'.

This will be equivalent to running a mirror cassandra db only better. If any of your DC's itself fails then the application using the database will not be affected and there is no downtime since it can still access data from the other DC.

Chethan